# Why is my jQuery .map not working here to combine my arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following code,

```
<script>

        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/InteractiveChart/jsonp?parameters={"Normalized":false,"NumberOfDays":1095,"DataPeriod":"Day","Elements":[{"Symbol":"AAPL","Type":"price","Params":["ohlc"]}]}',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {

       var x_axis = (JSON.stringify(data.Elements[0].DataSeries.close.values, null, '\t'));
       var y_axis = (JSON.stringify(data.Dates, null, '\t'));

       var r = [];

       r = $.map(y_axis, function(n, i) {
            return [[n, x_axis[i]]]; 
       });

       $('#container').html(r);       

   }
 });
</script>
```

Variables `x_axis` and `y_axis`are two single dimensional arrays and I am trying to combine them in to a single multi dimensional array using jQuery's .map function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's a link to what I've got so far - http://jsbin.com/wuxocivato/edit?html,output

Comment: are the length of the array are the some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `map` do not work as expected with strings... But you created strings with `JSON.stringify`. So it works:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/InteractiveChart/jsonp?parameters={"Normalized":false,"NumberOfDays":1095,"DataPeriod":"Day","Elements":[{"Symbol":"AAPL","Type":"price","Params":["ohlc"]}]}',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {

       var x_axis = data.Elements[0].DataSeries.close.values;
       var y_axis = data.Dates;

       var r = [];

       r = $.map(y_axis, function(n, i) {
            return [[n, x_axis[i]]]; 
       });
       console.log(r);   

       $('#container').html(r);       

   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: oh I see. That fixed my issue. Thank you :)